# Create Custom control from ajax control toolkit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a requirement where I need to show always visible calender. I understand that I can easily use ASP.NET calender, but because of the design of AJAX Control Toolkit calender and easiness of
using it, I am inclining towards creating a custom control out of it which can be visible by default.

For example:

When I load page, I should readily see AJAX calender without being associated to any id.

I have referred some links like

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETAJAXControlDevelopment.aspx

but I'm still not sure what's the right way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ASP.NET Calender is even easier to use than the AJAX control toolkit Calender. Just put the calender control in a Update Panel to AJAXify it.

Comment: but somehow it doesnt give that style and feel of ajax calender which i am looking for..

Comment: If there are not stock provided properties, then just see the style names used in final HTML and override it using JQuery. Or even better to use a JQuery callender

Comment: the problem using jquery or any other thing.the basic question is how to make them always visible. since all of them require a trigger of a button click or texbox focus to show up.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { }); Should be your trigger which fires after all the DOM objects are loaded.